# What is going on with this room’s wiring? Should I try to find where the circuit begins?

Tags: electrical, wiring, switch, receptacle, multiway-switch

[image]

So this room is wired strangely. The house is from the 1980s.

I am in the process of changing out old outlets and switches. Something is not working right.

I have researched 3 and 4 way switches and I am sure those are wired correctly. Common wire is in the right place for the 3 ways (dark screw). I can test the voltage and I can see that the common is coming from a different sheathing than the white/red, etc. 4 way switches are correctly wired as input and output pairs, each having 1 red and 1 black, and each pair coming from the same sheathing.

I have made sure that white wires are on the correct side of the outlets, and when there is a red, it is alone on one of the outlets and the tab is removed. In those cases where the outlets have a red wire, it is alone and the remaining two black wires are paired to the other outlet on the receptacle. White on one side, black/red on other.

I have a voltage meter which I use every time to check which wires are carrying a load.

I have a receptacle tester, and every out that works is reading as “correct” and grounded.

All of these switches and receptacles are on the same breaker. There are other outlets in the room though, along the two walls that don’t have as many outlets. Those are interior walls.

Should I try to figure out where this circuit “begins” so that I can troubleshoot it better?

Comment: Outlets with black and red wires mean two single or one double breaker(MWBC).  In the beginning some MWBC breakers were not together or had handle ties.  After a few people found out the hard(sparkly) way, handle ties were mandated.  You probably have outlets connected by the back stabs, change them all to the screws(with pigtails if needed).  Make sure you find the second breaker.  Some switches might be controlling some half of outlets, off switch, off outlet.

Comment: What exactly is the failure mode in question?

Comment: You have not described any trouble needing to be shot.

Comment: The problem is the outlets that are not working. I messed something up at some point, now I don’t know how to get started trying figure out the problem. It seems like everything is connected the way I’ve read it should be.